# Lumia 525 Headphone not detecting

Tags: nokia-lumia-525, sound

Headphone is not detecting in Lumia 525. But while restarting phone with headphone inserted, Headphone is working as usual. If removed, then again headphone is not detecting. Tried with various headphones but same problem is occurring.

Comment: Are u using the headphones given by Microsoft or some other brand?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions :
1. If it is software Problem :

- Reset your phone (Soft Reset),
- Hard Reset using Lumia Recovery Tool,

2. If it is Hardware Problem,

- If you had not visited Microsoft Store, Micosoft Care can Help.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

1. Remove all the headphones from Gadgets app and insert your headphone
   again.
2. If problem persists uninstall and reinstall the [Gadgets](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/gadgets/9wzdncrfj3df) app from the store.